# Create a many to many relation and give each relation an object

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, many-to-many

I am writing a query to create a database in SQL server 2008 R2. I plan to use it with entity framework in a mvc3 application

I have users, games and highscores.
What I want ot do is this:

I want to create a many-to-many relationship between users and games.

Each User can have multiple games and each game can have multiple users.

and each relation user-game has 1 high score.

So far I created the users, games, highscores tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    UserId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDate DateTime NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(32) NULL,
    Password VARCHAR(64),
    CONSTRAINT pk_users_userid PRIMARY KEY(UserId)
)
CREATE TABLE Games
(
    GameId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Url VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_gamess_gameid PRIMARY KEY(GameId)
)
CREATE TABLE Highscores
(
    HighscoreId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Value INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_surveyors_surveyorid PRIMARY KEY(HighscoreId)
)
```

What is the best way to create the many-to-many user-game relation and give each relation one high score? should I create a 4th table to hold the relation? And if I do so will I be able to use the database with Entity framework in an MVC3 application or would that complicate it?

Thank you

Additional note: I am planning to use this database with entity framework in a MVC 3 web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
     UserId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
     FirstName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
     LastName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
     Email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
     CreatedDate DateTime NULL,
     PhoneNumber VARCHAR(32) NULL,
     Password VARCHAR(64),
     CONSTRAINT pk_users_userid PRIMARY KEY(UserId)
)

CREATE TABLE Games (
   GameId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   Url VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_gamess_gameid PRIMARY KEY(GameId)
)

CREATE TABLE Highscores (
   HighscoreId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   UserID Int,
   GameID Int,
   Value INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_surveyors_surveyorid PRIMARY KEY(HighscoreId)
) 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Highscores]  ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Highscores_Games] FOREIGN KEY([GameID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Highscores]  ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Highscores_Users] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
```